# Very specific date formatting in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I'm trying to import a date "9:26 AM Thursday Feb 11, 2016" but it only shows "12:00 AM Thursday Feb 11, 2016"

```
$date = date("h:i A l M j, Y", strtotime("9:26 AM Thursday Feb 11, 2016"));echo $date;
```

Comment: might as well use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) with that specific format

Answer (score 4):

If you use the incredibly flexible `DatTime` class it is quite easy.

And using the `->format()` method once you have a valid date loaded you can output it in any format you like

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A l M j, Y', "09:26 AM Thursday Feb 11, 2016");
echo $d->format('h:i A l M j, Y');

echo $d->format('d/m/Y H:i');

echo $d->format('d/m/Y H:i l');
```

Gives this

```
09:26 AM Thursday Feb 11, 2016

11/02/2016 09:26

11/02/2016 09:26 Thursday
```